# I can not use Korean in Python pyautogui.typewrite

Tags: python, pyautogui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7GPT.jpg)

Sorry, I do not speak English well.

As shown in the image, English is executed, but Korean is not executed.

Why and what is the solution?

```
import pyautogui 
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world')
pyautogui.typewrite('안녕하세요')
```

or

```
file = open('test.txt') #Files with Korean characters
pyautogui.typewrite(file.read())
```

Comment: provide code instead of screenshot.

Comment: u can.. indirectly.. copy the string to clipboard, then invoke ctrl+V

Answer (score 0):

The `pyautogui` documentation says:

> The `typewrite()` Function
>   The primary keyboard function is `typewrite()`. This function will type the characters in the string is passed. To add a delay interval in between pressing each character key, pass an int or float for the interval keyword argument.
>   You can only press single-character keys with `typewrite()`, so you can’t press the `Shift` or `F1` keys, for example.

I think the same applies to `alt` sequences.